# react-router-dom's component parameter got undefined value

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm studying react right now, so I'm working with a hello world react project.

But when I successfully compiled the project, I just got an undefined value in Route's component parameter, below codes come from ReactDevTool in Firefox:

```
<HashRouter>
    <Router history={length:5, action: 'POP', location: {_}, _}
        <Route exact=true path='/' compenent=undefined></Route>
    </Router>
</HashRouter>
```

Here is my directory structure:

```
$ tree src/foreground/
src/foreground/
├── app.js
├── components
├── containers
│   └── Navigator
│       └── index.js
├── index.html
└── routes
```

entry file, app.js :

```
$ cat src/foreground/app.js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import { HashRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { View as Navigator } from './containers/Navigator';

render(
    <HashRouter>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Navigator} />
    </HashRouter>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

container Navigator:

```
$ cat src/foreground/containers/Navigator/index.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class View extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                sdfsdf
                <hr />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default View;
```

I expect webpage is a ***hr line with 'sdfsdf' above it***. But actually, I got an empty webpage.

**Question is**: How to get my expecting webpage ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're importing `Navigator` with a named import, but it's exported as a default export, so you'll need to either import the default:

```
import Navigator from './containers/Navigator';
```

or export `View` in `Navigator/index.js`:

```
export class View extends Component {..}
```